# JQuery $.getJSON Not Running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

I'm a J Query beginner. Need some help with the $.getJSON function. I am trying to retrieve data from an outside server using this function but when I run it, I get nothing. I've been through countless tutorials. Heres my code sample...

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url='https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/samples/v1/lts/Airport_response.json';
        $('#button').click(function(){
            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                $("#results").append(json.airport.name);
            });     
        });
    });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Go">
    <div id="results"></div>

</body>
```

and heres the JSON file content..

```
{
"airport":
        {
    "fs":"PDX",
    "iata":"PDX",
    "icao":"KPDX",
    "faa":"PDX",
    "name":"Portland International Airport",
    "street1":"7000 NE Airport Way",
    "city":"Portland",
    "cityCode":"PDX",
    "stateCode":"OR",
    "postalCode":"97218",
    "countryCode":"US",
    "countryName":"United States"
        }

        }
```

Im just trying to grab the 'name' content. Is $.getJSON the correct function or should I use $.ajax or $.get?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you including two versions of jquery?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If you print out `json.airport.name` using `console.log`, what shows up?

Comment: @naomik Because you can never have enough jQuery.

Comment: You can't make Ajax request to third-party servers, unless they enable CORS. And this one doesn't seem to. Fortunately they seem to support JSONP. Have a look at https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/how_to.

Comment: @FelixKling It seems that they support JSONP, though.

Comment: Some elemental debugging is required here.  What errors show in the debug console?  if you put a `console.log(json)` statement in your getJSON success handler, what does it show and does it get hit?  If you use `$.getJSON(...).fail(function() {console.log("fail");})` does that get hit?  This is basic javascript troubleshooting - worth learning.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/samples/v1/lts/Airport_response.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Your title is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that .getJSON is not able to return data for that url.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/samples/v1/lts/Airport_response.json. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

If you control the website flightstats.com you can add the necessary headers for that. If you don't you probably want to create a lightweight server side fetch to display the necessary json using proper CORS responses.

For more information than I can easily place in a stackoverflow page about CORS, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: It appears that the complete answer is the OP should switch to `$.get()` and use JSONP as the format since the API supports that and it works cross origin.

Comment: I admit to not knowing what flightstats.com offers in terms of API. I was addressing the question of why the getJSON itself was not working. As a jQuery piece. But yes, if flightstats.com supports JSONP an answer that uses .get and JSONP would be more complete for this very specific answer of flightstats.com API usage.

Comment: @Callek , CORS seemed a little confusing to me. Using $.get and JSONP worked perfectly. Thanks guys